# Particle Help On Commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

On minecraft, I have this command:

```
execute @e[name=unknown] ~ ~ ~ particle smoke ~ ~ ~ particle smoke ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 1 100
```

What it should do it spawn particles when the fishing rod 'bobber' is but instead I get the error:

```
[19:52:51] Failed to execute 'particle smoke ~ ~ ~ particle smoke ~ ~ ~ 0 0 0 1 100' as unknown
```

Any help on fixing my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#particle) , the particle command should be used like this:

```
particle <name> <x> <y> <z> <xd> <yd> <zd> <speed> [count] [mode]
```

`x`, `y`, and `z` specify the location.

`xd`, `yd`, and `zd` specify the size of the area to create particles in.

`speed` is the speed of the particles.

---

In your case, the command would be `execute @e[name=unknown] ~ ~ ~ particle smoke ~ ~ ~ <xd> <yd> <zd> <speed>`.

You cannot use tilde (~) notation for the size of the area. You must specify an *absolute* value.